# Angular 2 - Update *ngFor table after data has changed

Tags: arrays, angular

Normally I would expect this to update in realtime, but it doesn't seem to be doing so.  In my angular app, I have an array that stores a string and another array like so:

```
var myArray= [{id:"name1",array:{"id1", "id2"}]
```

And then in my html I have a table that lists every item in `myArray` in a row

```
<table *ngFor="item in myArray">
   <td>{{item.id}}</td>
   <td>{{item.array}}</td>
</table>
```

The items in the `array` are added in a function that is bound to a button click.  So the users will chose from a list of items, click a button, and those choices get pushed to the `array`.  They are also able to go back and delete some of those items, so I am adding in code to handle the check every item in `myArray`, and if its `array` contains that item that was deleted, it will remove it.

```
for(let i=0; i<myArray.length;i++) {
  let row:any = myArray[i];
  for(let k=0; k<row.array.length;k++) {
    if(row.array[k] == deletedItem) {
      row.array.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

The code works, using console logs I am able to see that the `deletedItem` is removed from any item in `myArray`'s `array` (sorry for the confusing variable names!).  However, the table doesn't reflect the updated values, even when `myArray` shows it when submitting or printing to console.  Do I have to refresh the table?  I thought it should update automatically since the data is bound.

Comment: It is confusing of course, not just because of the variable names, but since it is not clear what they represent in your code. For example, `index` & `deletedItem`. Please either create a reproduction or give sufficient info for someone to debug it. Also, it seems your `array` property within `myArray` is defined as an `object` not an `array`. Are you calculating the `length` of it in `row.array.length` in its intended way?

Comment: @amal I'm just trying to demonstrate my delete code.  It's not updating the table, even though the delete code is working (verified by console logs).  I'm just wondering if I need to update the table somehow

Comment: Could you please clarify this assignment: `var myArray= [{id:"name1",array:{"id1", "id2"}]`? Looks like it is missing one closing `}`

Answer (score 0):

From this code, I think you are not deleting any element from myArray, but from the local variable row. That's why in your template, you don't see any change.

Try with this :

```
for(let i=0; i<myArray.length;i++) {
  let row:any = myArray[i];
  for(let k=0; k<row.array.length;k++) {
    if(row.array[k] == deletedItem) {
      myArray[i].array.splice(k, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The code itself is fine, when I check using console logs I can see the item is deleted in my global `myArray` object.  The problem is that visually in the table the value is not reflected correctly.

Comment: Can you make a StackBlitz example ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today and nearly tore my hair out trying to figure it out. Just like you, my console.log looked right but my data wasn't updating even though it was bound. The reason it won't update is that the data source is immutable and the only way to have it update is by assigning the spliced ArrayList to a new array and then assigning it to the data source.

The data I'm going to use is from https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview this is their property, not mine.

EX:

```
const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];

this.dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;


remove(){

        //this is where I splice

        this.dataSource.splice(1,1);

        //this is where I assign it to the new array.

        const ELEMENT_DATAS: PeriodicElements[]=[...this.dataSource];

        //this sets the new array to the data source updating it and updating the 
          table on the UI

        this.dataSource = ELEMENT_DATAS;


    }
```